# How use Facebook Javascript SDK response in Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, json, facebook-javascript-sdk, javascript-objects

Supposing I have the following code which returns a Javascript object which I can read in Firebug's console:

```
FB.api('/me',function(apiresponse){
    console.log(apiresponse);
});
```

How can I then use the data from `apiresponse` in an Ajax request on the same page?

Currently my Ajax request looks as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    // CodeIgniter URL
    url: "<?=site_url?>('login/add_fb_users'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: apiresponse,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

I know very little about Javascript, but reading around the subject leads me to think I have to convert the Javascript object to a JSON string. Is that correct? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your AJAX call inside the handler for the API call like below..

```
FB.api('/me', function(apiresponse){
    console.log(apiresponse);

    $.ajax({
        // CodeIgniter URL
        url: "<?=site_url?>('login/add_fb_users'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: apiresponse,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The most annoying problems are the easiest to fix. Works a treat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way:

- define a global variable in your javascript, e.g. var myVar1;
- set apireponse to the global variable in your FB.api callback (i.e. where u call console.log)
- reference the var myVar1 in your ajax fcn.

Comment: If I do that, and `alert(myVar1)`, it just returns "undefined". Have I missed something?

Comment: have u set the value at that moment?